# How to use setInterval() in react?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to learn react and I am trying to create a working clock

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    function tick() {
      return new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    }
    return <h1>{tick()}</h1>; 
    //I want to use setInterval(tick, 1000) here so I can call the tick function every 1 sec
  }
}
export default App;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You should use setInterval in a useEffect and **don't forget to return the clear interval from the useEffect** so that it gets removed on unmount:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    console.log('This will run every second!');
  }, 1000);
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

Comment: Upvoting this answer because you actually explain the code :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this code :D

```
useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(tick, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(timer)
}, [])
```

Comment: Oh no, I haven't learned yet the useEffect. I will read and will see how can I implement it. Thanks

Comment: This tells what useEffect is :D https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect

Comment: If my answer helped you, pls select my answer :D Thx!